# PCL linker error related to VTK

Tags: compiler-errors, makefile, vtk, archlinux

Trying to compilepcl 1.7.2
**machine:** Archlinux

**other libs:** vtk 6.2.x

I'm getting following make error:

```
Building CXX object io/tools/CMakeFiles/pcl_convert_pcd_ascii_binary.dir/convert_pcd_ascii_binary.cpp.o
[  6%] Linking CXX executable ../../bin/pcl_convert_pcd_ascii_binary
/usr/lib/libvtkIOParallel.so.1: undefined reference to `Json::Value::operator[](std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)'
/usr/lib/libvtkIOParallel.so.1: undefined reference to `Json::Value::getMemberNames[abi:cxx11]() const'
/usr/lib/libvtkIOParallel.so.1: undefined reference to `Json::Reader::getFormattedErrorMessages[abi:cxx11]() const'
/usr/lib/libvtkIOParallel.so.1: undefined reference to `Json::Value::asString[abi:cxx11]() const'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
io/tools/CMakeFiles/pcl_convert_pcd_ascii_binary.dir/build.make:287: polecenia dla obiektu 'bin/pcl_convert_pcd_ascii_binary' nie powiodły się
make[2]: *** [bin/pcl_convert_pcd_ascii_binary] Błąd 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:332: polecenia dla obiektu 'io/tools/CMakeFiles/pcl_convert_pcd_ascii_binary.dir/all' nie powiodły się
make[1]: *** [io/tools/CMakeFiles/pcl_convert_pcd_ascii_binary.dir/all]
```

Could anyone tell me what are those references *Json::Value* ? 
Is this part of VTK - or some optional lib?

Any ideas for fix?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that Archlinux & pcl requires jsoncpp library to be installed too.
(It is an optional dependency of VTK).